# What does "both actions within 12 hours" mean?

Tags: support, edits, badges

For example the [**Refiner** badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4369/refiner) has the following definition:

> Edited and answered 50 questions (**both actions within 12 hours**, answer score > 0).

what does that mean, is it really possible that I edited and answered 50 questions in 12 hours? I don't feel like I did.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to post *one* answer, and have edited the question the answer belongs with in a 24 hour window, e.g. up to 12 hours before you posted that answer, or up to 12 hours after you posted your answer.

Then repeat that action 50 times; you can post 1 answer every week and earn the badge after about a year (provided all your answers receive an upvote), for example.

In other words, the 12 hours do not apply to how fast you can post 50 answers. It limits when you can edit the question. You cannot go back to all your old answers and edit the question because those are too old, but you can edit a question *now*, and post a new answer to that question shortly after, or post a new answer and edit the question shortly after and the answer will qualify as one of the 50.

Comment: Oh this makes a lot of sense, just what you did  now, so now you added 1 to your count.

Comment: I just edited your question and my answer has a score of +1, so this answer now counts as one of the 500 for the Illuminator badge (I already have the Refiner badge). Even I cannot post 500 answers in 12 hours. I know, hard to believe!