# lluminator badge description unclear

Tags: feature-request, badges

The [Illuminator Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4370/illuminator) description says

> Edit and answer 500 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)

For about the first year of using Stack Overflow I thought this meant doing all 500 edits in 12 hours. Other people have been confused by this, too (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272533/3681880) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284572/3681880)).

With a little research, anyone can learn [what this badge means](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284573/3681880), but I'm suggesting that we change the wording to something that makes it clear right away.

Answer (score 4):

This would be a little more clear:

> Edit and answer 500 questions (both actions **for each question** within 12 hours, answer score > 0)

Or perhaps something like [what Patrice suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272534/3681880).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest

> (Edit and answer a question within 12 hours, answer score > 0 ) ←
>   Repeat 500 times!